# How can I use shadow to create a solid border?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a border using `box-shadow` `inset`, because of the condition i am not able to use the `border-box` on one of the `a` element. But not getting. any help?

```css
.parent{
  background: #FFF;
  padding:5rem;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
```

Comment: where and why you want to use `border-box` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the horizontal and vertical offset (value) of the shadow to 0px such as:

```
   box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
```

```css
.parent{
  background: #FFF;
  padding:5rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want equal border-width on all sides - just remove `offset-x` and `offset-y`:

```css
.parent{
  background: #c9c9c9;
  padding:5rem;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you cannot use the `border` property here is different techniques that allow you to create a border for your element:

### **Using outline**

```css
.parent{
  background: #FFF;
  padding:5rem;
  outline:2px solid rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
```

### **Using Box-shadow**

```css
.parent{
  background: #FFF;
  padding:5rem;
  margin:5px;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
.parent.inset {
  
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 2px rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>


<div class="parent inset"></div>
```

### **Using gradient**

```css
.parent{
  background: #FFF;
  padding:5rem;
  margin:5px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) top/100% 2px,
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) bottom/100% 2px,
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) left/2px 100%,
   linear-gradient(#000,#000) right/2px 100%; 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
```

Another way with gradient if you want to have a `background-color`:

```css
.parent{
  background: #FFF;
  padding:5rem;
  margin:5px;
  background:
   linear-gradient(pink,pink) center/calc(100% - 4px) calc(100% - 4px),
   linear-gradient(#000,#000); 
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
```